# Proper way to start new thread from service layer using spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, service

I have a method that will be rarely called. This method collect garbage in db. I don't want to make user to wait for server response so i decided to call this method from new thread from my service layer. i'm using Spring.
Service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UploadService {

    @Resource(name = "UploadDAO")
    private UploadDao uploadDao;
```

Method that i don't want to wait for

```
public void collectBlobGarbage(){
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                uploadDao.collectBlobGarbage();
            }
        });
        th.start();
    }
```

Is it a good way to do like this?

Comment: You can look at this example: https://www.concretepage.com/spring/example_threadpooltaskexecutor_spring

Comment: Thanks for help.

Comment: @Noixes, could you please explain your example how, this part,
               `AsyncTask task= ctx.getBean(AsyncTask.class);
  task.doAsyncTask();`
starts a new thread?

When I'm trying to execute your example, it does not start a new thread, rather than it's being executed sequentially without starting a new thread.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have Spring on your classpath you might as well use @Async

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Void> collectBlobGarbage() throws InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture.completeFuture(uploadDao.collectBlobGarbage());
}
```

On your main class you need to use `@EnableAsync` like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

And you need an executor bean:

```
@Bean
public Executor asyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Stackoverflow-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the provided solution can potentially cause a lot of threads on you server.

As an alternative, you can consider using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` in such a way that you will get an executor service that is limited only to one thread—so you will never create more than one thread—and that is what you need.

Also as you are using Spring, consider configuring a `SingleThreadExecutor` instantiation as a separate bean—in such a way that you will be able to change the implementation of `ExecutorService` in the future.